# Route public subnet over VPN.

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a dedicated server I rent at OVH and have a /27 IP address allocation. All of my servers have Debian 8 and I would like to use a VPN (OpenVPN) to route some of the public IP addresses to another remote location through the VPN. I know I can just forward packets using `iptables` to the IP address of the VPN client, but this is not what I'm asking. I would like to use my OVH IP addresses on my remote server, in a setup using containers so each container can have its own (DDoS protected) OVH IP address, and in the container it would show it has the OVH IP address - not a private IP address. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: i have a tap0 interface bridged to vmbr0 (has eth0 as well in the bridge) on my ovh server. on the client machine it has eth0,tap0,br0 bridged. at ovh i have a ipv6 subnet as well, and i successfully have added ipv6 ip addresses to the vpn client over the bridge.

Comment: the problem is that my server has an initial ip (158.69.x.32) and the gateway is 158.69.x.254. then i have an extra allocation in a different subnet at 192.99.x.x so in order to add the wacky default gateway i first must route add 158.69.x.254 dev br0 and then set it as default gw, but when i do this i lose all connectivity and must reboot vpn client. so thats where i am stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using a TAP interface on OpenVPN - ie bridging the 2 networks together, but that would seem like a slow, error prone and generally horrible way to do it.

An alternative would be to break your /27 into 2/28's and route one of the /28s to the remote location.   This would waste a fair few IP's but would provide a decent logical framework which you can use with the TUN interface and some route commands in your configuration.

That said, and making possibly incorrect assumptions about the kind of traffic you are planning on running, using some kind of load balancer [ even a crude one like iptables ] is the better way of doing something like this 99 times out of 100.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a tap0 interface in openvpn.

I was successful in doing what i asked so i will post the answer for others.

My OVH machine has a single assigned ip on a different subnet than my extra ip allocations.

OVH: main ip (158.69.1.18)
OVH: extra subnet: 192.99.1.208-223

Server2: 72.34.43.34

Start by following the instructions at: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#install

Install openvpn and create your keys. Create keys for server 2/vpn client and copy them to server 2 in the /etc/openvpn folder (or wherever you want)

Find the server configuration file mentioned in the above url and copy it from its original location to /etc/openvpn/server.conf on your vpn server.

Make sure it has the following settings:

```
dev tap0
server-bridge 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.5 10.8.0.5
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
client-to-client
```

Leave everything else default. 10.8.0.5 10.8.0.5 make it so it only has 1 lan ip in its pool to give out. This is for a vpn with 1 client bridged. You may need to change this but probably will not

Set up the config on your client server

```
client
dev tap0
proto udp
remote 158.69.1.18 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client1.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client1.key  # This file should be kept
```

Start the server and client.

Create a bridge on your ovh server

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 tap0
brctl addif br0 eth0 (main ethernet interface)
```

Add an ip to your tap device and bridge

```
ip addr add 18.8.0.1 dev tap0
ip addr add 10.8.0.2 dev br0
route add -net 10.8.0.0/24 dev br0
```

If your main ip is not in your ip allocations subnet, add an ip from that subnet to your bridge. If it IS, skip this.

```
ip addr add 192.99.1.208 dev br0
```

Add an ip to your tap0 interface on vpn client

```
ip addr add 10.8.0.6 dev tap0
```

Add your OVH ip to the tap interface on vpn client

```
ip addr add 192.99.1.210 dev tap0
```

Add a default gateway to tap0

```
route add default gw 192.99.1.208 dev tap0
```

Log in to OVH or SYS and go to where you manage your ip addresses, pick an ip and create a virtual mac for it then wait for the mac to appear and set that mac address as the mac of your tap0 interface on your vpn client.

```
ifconfig tap0 hw ether 02:00:00:xx:yy:zz
```

Now your OVH ip should be working on your vpn client.